# How to Integrate Kal Calendar?

Tags: ios, xcode, api, calendar, kal

I am fairly new to iOS development, and have a project in mind that would benefit from a third-party calendar interface.  However, I'm having trouble just getting started.  Feeling a little disappointed as well because I have searched high and low and it seems everyone is capable of integrating Kal Calendar itself, and that is where I am stuck.

I have downloaded the .zip source [here](https://github.com/phaibin/Kal) and am trying to follow the steps.  The first three are as follows:

1. Clone the Kal git repository: `git clone git://github.com/klazuka/Kal.git`. Make sure you store the repository in a permanent place because Xcode will need to reference the files every time you compile your project.
2. Locate the "Kal.xcodeproj" file under `Kal/src/`. Drag Kal.xcodeproj and drop it onto the root of your Xcode project's "Groups and Files" sidebar. A dialog will appear -- make sure "Copy items" is unchecked and "Reference Type" is "Relative to Project" before clicking "Add".
3. Now you need to link the Kal static library to your project. Select the Kal.xcodeproj file that you just added to the sidebar. Under the "Details" table, you will see libKal.a. Check the checkbox on the far right for this file. This will tell Xcode to link against Kal when building your app.

I have dragged the Kal.xcodeproj file  from Finder into the root of my project in the Project Navigator as seen in this image: [image]

Is this the correct place to drop the Kal.xcodeproj file?  I was not presented with a dialog upon doing so. What is the "Groups and Files" sidebar?  Upon selecting the Kal.xcodeproj file from where I have placed it, I cannot find a "Details" table where a libKal.a file is located.

Again, my apologies as I am fairly new to iOS dev, and I completely understand that these could be the most amateur questions out there.  If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.  Just looking for some help getting started so I can finally begin my project.

By the way, I'm using Xcode 6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to expand the Kal.xcodeproj by clicking on the arrow. Under products folder, you will find libKal.a

Comment: @Ritu I did find libKal.a in that folder previously, but upon clicking it where will I find the "Details" table and the checkbox to the far right that is mentioned in step 3?  My apologies if it is an obvious answer, I am currently at work but I recall looking at libKal.a previously and not finding the table or checkbox

Comment: You should just drag this file into Build Phases of your project Target. And setting the target dependency should work.